# Export from Google Calender to Excel

Tags: web-applications, calendar, export

I need to do the opposite of what people normally try. An online service is not a viable solution, since I am using sensitive data.
Building in Excel Master did provide the needed result.

Comment: is it a solution to export the google calendar data to csv and then import in excel? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJ_B2P4gLOA

Comment: There is sensetive information in my calender, private. When downloading to on line service  there is a risk to loose it. But can I copy somehow the the hidden structure of positive resault of this conversion?

Comment: Google calendar IS an online service, so I don't entirely see the issue...

Comment: One line servce youve mentioned, has no reputation , demands the upload of a file.

Comment: aah . i had not wathched it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the google calendar  which is in .ics format.

This needs to be converted to csv, or another format which excel can parse. You either need to code your own converter or use something like [this one on github](https://github.com/johnyluyte/ICS-to-Excel-CSV) which can be run from your local machine.

Be aware that you most likely need to run a http server on your machine to run it for any js includes.